# Boot loader doesn't jump to kernel code

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I'm writing small operation system - for practice. I started with bootloader.
 I want to create small command system that runs in 16 bit real mode (for now).
I've created bootloader that resets drive, then loads sector after bootloader.
The problem is because after `jmp` function nothing actually happening.

I't trying to load next sector at 0x7E00 (I'm not totally sure how to point address using es:bx so that may be a problem, I believe that its Address:offset), just after bootloader.

This is the code:

```
;
; SECTOR 0x0
;

;dl is number of harddrive where is bootloader
org 0x7C00
bits 16

;reset hard drive
xor ah,ah
int 0x13
;read sectors
clc
mov bx,0x7E00
mov es,bx
xor bx,bx
mov ah,0x02 ;function
mov al,0x1  ;sectors to read
mov ch,0x0  ;tracks
mov cl,0x1  ;sector
mov dh,0x0  ;head
int 0x13
;if not readed jmp to error
jc error
;jump to 0x7E00 - executed only if loaded
jmp 0x7E00
error:
    mov si,MSGError
    .loop:
        lodsb
        or al,al
        jz .end
        mov ah,0x0E
        int 0x10
        jmp .loop
    .end:
        hlt
MSGError db "Error while booting", 0x0
times 0x1FE - ($ - $$) db 0x0
db 0x55
db 0xAA

;
; SECTOR 0x1
;

jmp printtest
;definitions
MSGLoaded db "Execution successful", 0x0
;
; Print function
; si - message to pring (NEED TO BE FINISHED WITH 0x0)

printtest:
    mov si,MSGLoaded
    .loop:
        lodsb
        or al,al
        jz .end
        mov ah,0x0E
        int 0x10
        jmp .loop
    .end:
        hlt

times 0x400 - ($-$$) db 0x0
```

I've been testing this code using VirtualBox but nothing actually happens, The read error doesn't shows, as well as message that should be printed.

Comment: Before issuing any BIOS interrupts you need to setup the Stack (`SS` and `SP` registers). You also need to call `CLD` or `STD` before using lodsb and related functions. Your code assumes auto increment so after setting up stack call `CLD`. You also don't seem to setup the `DS` register with a proper segment (lodsb likely won't work otherwise). It isn't clear from what you have presented what the origin point for your kernel image was set to. Your makefile or commands you use to link,compile, create disk image would be beneficial in your question.

Comment: `mov bx,0x7E00`; `mov es,bx`,`xor bx, bx` seems like it might be wrong. Your code suggests you intend to load the sector from disk at `0x0000:0x7E00`=physical address `0x7E00`, but you set `ES`:`BX` segment to `0x7E00` and `BX` to zero yielding a physical address of 0x7E00<<4+0x0000=`0x7E000` . I think you meant to set `ES` to `0x07E0` which would yield a physical address of 0x07E0<<4+0x0000=physical address `0x7E00` . You basically loaded your kernel far higher into memory than you intended. Try changing ``mov bx,0x7E00` to `mov bx,0x07E0`

Comment: The orgin of my kernel is sector 0x1. I'm compile with use `nasm bootloader.asm -o bootloader.img' (bootloader.asm is code that is in main thread). then setting up bootloader.img as floppy in VirtualBox. about `lodsb` it have worked when instead `jc` I used `jnc` to show error message when reading actually finished successfully.

Comment: You say nothing prints, and I think that is mainly because you do NOT set a `DS` register that `lodsb` will need. At the start of your boot loader you should set `DS` up manually, and in this case it should be set to 0. So `xor ax, ax` and `mov ds, ax` (or anything equivalent of moving 0 to DS) will definitely help. I do believe in all likelihood the fact you see nothing printed is because DS is wrong (not set). You can't rely on BIOS to jump to your boot loader with proper values for DS, ES, SS, and SP

Comment: I had added the things that you said but still it doesn't work right. The kernel prints message but its not "Execution successful" but its prints "Ä┼╝" which suggests to me that instead loading message to si, its loading random thing from RAM

Comment: There also seems to be a problem with the sector number you are reading. If your intent is to read the 512 byte sector right after the MBR (bootloader) then shouldn't it be `mov cl,0x2  ;sector` instead of `mov cl,0x1  ;sector`?

Comment: You say the KERNEL prints messages, but you say it can't load. Do you mean the BOOTLOADER prints messages?

Comment: You was right with sector number, I've changed it and the kernel printed message normally. I don't know why its printed "Ä┼╝" before, but its works now. I am really thankful.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The primary problems with this code were:

1. *ES:BX* was pointing to the wrong segment:offset to load the kernel into
2. Wrong sector was being loaded so kernel wasn't what was expected

The first one was in this code:

```
mov bx,0x7E00
mov es,bx
xor bx,bx
```

The question wants to load the sector from disk to `0x0000:0x7E00`(*ES:BX*). This code sets the *ES:BX* to `0x7E00:0x0000` which resolves to a physical address of `0x7E000` ((0x7E00<<4)+0x0000). I think the intention was to load `0x07E0` into *ES* which would yield a physical address of `0x7E00` ((0x07E0<<4)+0x0000). You can learn more about 16:16 memory addressing calculations [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171207141924/http://www.internals.com:80/articles/protmode/realmode.htm). Multiplying the segment by 16 is the same as shifting it left 4 bits.

The second problem in the code is here:

```
mov ah,0x02 ;function
mov al,0x1  ;sectors to read
mov ch,0x0  ;tracks
mov cl,0x2  ;sector number
mov dh,0x0  ;head
int 0x13
```

The number for the second 512 block sector on the disk is 2, not 1. So to fix the above code you need to set *CL* accordingly:

```
mov cl,0x2  ;sector number
```

## General Tips for Bootloader Development

Other issues that can trip up running code on various emulators, virtual machines and real physical hardware that should be addressed are:

1. When the BIOS jumps to your code you can't rely on *CS*,*DS*,*ES*,*SS*,*SP* registers having valid or expected values. They should be set up appropriately when your bootloader starts. You can only be guaranteed that your bootloader will be loaded and run from physical address 0x00007c00 and that the boot drive number is loaded into the *DL* register.
2. Set *SS:SP* to memory that you know won't conflict with the operation of your own code. The BIOS may have placed its default stack pointer anywhere in the first megabyte of usable and addressable RAM. There is no guarantee as to where that is and whether it will be suitable for the code you write.
3. The direction flag used by `lodsb`, `movsb` etc could be either set or cleared. If the direction flag is set improperly *SI*/*DI* registers may be adjusted in the wrong direction. Use `STD`/`CLD` to set it to the direction you wish (CLD=forward/STD=backwards). In this case the code assumes forward movement so one should use `CLD`. More on this can be found in an [instruction set reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20171119031157/https://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_29.html)
4. When jumping to a kernel it is generally a good idea to *FAR JMP* to it so that it properly sets *CS:IP* to expected values. This can avoid problems with kernel code that may do *absolute near* *JMPs* and *CALLs* within the same segment.
5. If targeting your boot loader for 16-bit code that works on 8086/8088 processors (AND higher) avoid usage of 32 bit registers in assembly code. Use *AX*/*BX*/*CX*/*DX*/*SI*/*DI*/*SP*/*BP* instead of *EAX*/*EBX*/*ECX*/*EDX*/*ESI*/*EDI*/*ESP*/*EBP*. Although not an issue in this question, it has been an issue for others seeking help. A 32 bit processor can utilizes 32 bit registers in 16-bit real mode, but an 8086/8088/80286 can't since they were 16 bit processors without access to extended 32 bit registers.
6. *FS* and *GS* segment registers were added to 80386+ CPUs. Avoid them if you intend to target 8086/8088/80286.
7. **Note: This is a very common issue asked about on Stackoverflow**: If you are intending to boot as USB media using floppy disk emulation (FDD) on real hardware you may need to have a BIOS Parameter Block (BPB) in your boot sector. You can find more detailed information in this [related Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320115/3857942) which provides an example BPB and a tool to see if your BIOS overwrites data in the BPB after loading your boot sector into memory.

To resolve the first and second item this code can be used near the start of the boot loader:

```
xor ax,ax      ; We want a segment of 0 for DS for this question
mov ds,ax      ;     Set AX to appropriate segment value for your situation
mov es,ax      ; In this case we'll default to ES=DS
mov bx,0x8000  ; Stack segment can be any usable memory

cli            ; Disable interrupts to circumvent bug on early 8088 CPUs
mov ss,bx      ; This places it with the top of the stack @ 0x80000.
mov sp,ax      ; Set SP=0 so the bottom of stack will be @ 0x8FFFF
sti            ; Re-enable interrupts

cld            ; Set the direction flag to be positive direction
```

A couple things to note. When you change the value of the *SS* register (in this case via a `MOV`) the processor is supposed to turn off interrupts for that instruction and keep them off until *after* the following instruction. Normally you don't need to worry about disabling interrupts if you update *SS* followed immediately by an update of *SP*. There is a bug in very early 8088 processors where this wasn't honored so if you are targeting the widest possible environments it is a safe bet to explicitly disable and re-enable them. If you don't intend to ever work on a buggy 8088 then the `CLI`/`STI` instructions can be removed in the code above. I know about this bug first hand with work I did in the mid 80s on my home PC.

The second thing to note is how I set up the stack. For people new to 8088/8086 16-bit assembly the stack can be set a multitude of ways. In this case I set the top of the stack (lowest part in memory) at `0x8000`(*SS*). I then set the stack pointer (*SP*) to `0`. When you [push something on the stack](https://web.archive.org/web/20171108151536/http://x86.renejeschke.de:80/html/file_module_x86_id_269.html) in 16-bit real mode the processor first decrements the stack pointer by 2 and then places a 16-bit *WORD* at that location. Thus the first push to the stack would be at 0x0000-2 = 0xFFFE (-2). You'd then have an *SS:SP* that looks like `0x8000:0xFFFE` . In this case the stack runs from `0x8000:0x0000` to `0x8000:0xFFFF`.

When dealing with the stack running on an 8086(doesn't apply to 80286,80386+ processors) it is a good idea to set the stack pointer (*SP*) to an even number. On the original 8086 if you set *SP* to an odd number you would incur a [4 clock cycle penalty](http://zsmith.co/intel.html) for every access to stack space. Since the 8088 had an 8 bit data bus this penalty didn't exist, but loading a 16-bit *word* on 8086 took 4 clock cycles whereas it took 8 clock cycles on the 8088 (two 8 bit memory reads).

Lastly, If you want to explicitly set *CS:IP* so that *CS* is properly set by the time the *JMP* is complete (to your kernel) then it is recommended to do a [FAR JMP](http://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation) (*See Operations that affect segment registers*/*FAR Jump*). In NASM syntax the `JMP` would look like this:

```
jmp 0x07E0:0x0000
```

Some (ie MASM/MASM32) assemblers don't have direct support to encode a *FAR Jmp* so one way it can be done is manually like this:

```
db 0x0ea     ; Far Jump instruction
dw 0x0000    ; Offset
dw 0x07E0    ; Segment
```

If using GNU assembler it would look like:

```
ljmpw $0x07E0,$0x0000
```

Comment: When a human uses GNU assembler for x86 it looks like `.intel_syntax noprefix` `jmp 0x07E0:0x0000`

Comment: Where you wrote "To resolve the first and second item this code", the code snippet initialises registers DS,ES,SS and SP. What about the CS register, should we just leave this register as is? Or what change would you recommend?

Comment: @supmethods : That is a good question. I do have a question and answer here on that very topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548325/near-call-jump-tables-dont-always-work-in-a-bootloader  . You only need to set CS at the beginning of your bootloader **if** it uses instructions that are relative to CS. A lot of bootloader code doesn't require CS to be a specific value. The Q&A link show some scenarios where that may be the case. If you code a bootloader to avoid them then it ill be okay. If you are unsure you can do a FAR JMP near the beginning of the bootloader to set CS as well.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read the comments and surrounding text when posting my comment. A bad habit, yes.

Comment: Another common gotcha when booting on real hardware: the BIOS may overwrite 59 bytes of your bootloader with a BPB starting after 3 bytes.  [Custom bootloader booted via USB drive produces incorrect output on some computers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47277702) .  Also writing it safely to a USB stick, writing to the top-level MBR and waiting for `sync` to flush the write buffer: [bootloader works in qemu but fails in virtualbox and on hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62484061)